# Select first available font XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

How to select first available font from the list of suitable fonts?

Currently I use `\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}` command in Ubuntu and `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` in Windows environment. I would like to automate the selection of the font.
It would be perfect if `\setmainfont` could accept several fonts, e.g. `\setmainfont{Liberation Serif, Times New Roman}`, but it cannot. I am looking for any kind of workaround.

**Update** Is it possible to check if a font is available? Or is there a way to catch the unhandled exception `fontspec error: "font-not-found"`?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Which font should the final document use?

Comment: @quinmars I am creating a document style. I wish that users of this style wouldn't have to configure anything, no matter which operating system they use. Bouth ```Liberation Serif``` and ```Times New Roman``` fonts are almost the same, so it can be any of them.

Comment: I wouldn't select a font in the document class/style. Then people could also use pdflatex for example. If you insist on selecting the font in your style/class I would use something like TeX Gyre Termes, which should be available on all modern tex installations. IMHO the look of a document should not depend on the used operating system.

Comment: @quinmars Thank you very much. I used TeX Gyre Termes like this ```\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Extension=.otf, UprightFont= *-regular, BoldFont=*-bold, ItalicFont=*-italic, BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic]{texgyretermes}```.

Comment: Just to note that another issue with your original plan is that there's no guarantee that GNU/Linux users will have Liberation Serif available. I guess TNR is available by default in Windows, but there's no such assurance for GNU/Linux systems, no matter which font you choose.

Comment: The approach is somewhat flawed. What if the user of the class uses OpenBSD or OSX or Solaris or ...?  If you want to set a default font, use one that has (long!) come with a TeX Live distribution. How far back you go can then depend on what other packages are fundamentally essential to your class. You should rely on a very simple baseline font, and simply note in the docs how easy it is to override with a `\setmainfont` command.  Of course, if it's just for your personal use, then you can be more dogmatic and idiosyncratic about what fonts your class requires.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the [`ifplatform`](ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/ifplatform/ifplatform.pdf) package.

Shell escape must be enabled for this to work, but try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}   
\iflinux
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\else
\ifwindows
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\fi
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

FYI, there is also [`ifxetex`](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.pdf), which is nice for setting up fonts, encodings, etc. based on your chosen typesetting engine.

Comment: As @cfr mentioned, there is no assurance for GNU/Linux systems that Liberation Serif font will be installed. I would like to provide a list of suitable fonts for Linux.

Comment: @niekas I realize this doesn't achieve your goal as explained in the comments, but it does what you explained in the question (before the update, in which you ask a separate question). So, I thought I'd submit this answer anyway, in case it is helpful to someone searching this topic in the future.